# JQuery expression returning the first table row as an array of strings?

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-table, row

I'm new to JQuery. I need a JQuery expression returning the first table row as an array of strings?

```
<table id='table1'>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

In this case it should give `['A','B','C']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) jQuery function to create a new array from a jQuery object, like so:

```
var newArray = $('#table1 tr:first td').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CYr2S/)

Comment: @user1069609 The output in the jsFiddle demo is the result of the HTML, not the Javascript.

Comment: What if I wanted to exclude the first column of the row, would I just remove it from the array in another statement?

Comment: @Rod Easiest way would be to not select it. If you wanted the values from all columns except the first in only the first row, you could modify the `td` part of the selector to `td:not(:first-child)` (i.e. all TD elements that aren't the first child of their parent).

Answer (score 2):

```
var v =   $("tr:first> td").map(function(i,j){
return $(j).text();
});

console.log(v);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvnjJ/2/)

[jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)